# Rotations of eigenstates of $S_z$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-spin, rotation, spinors

I have a question regarding the rotation of spinors in a spin-1/2 system.

We have a Spin generator $\hat{S}$ for rotations of spinors. 
A rotation around the axis $\vec{n}$ with the angle $\phi$ 
is generated by the operator:

$$
D_{\vec{n}}(\phi) = \exp(-i\phi \hat{S}\cdot \vec{n})
$$

This operator can also be written, for a rotation about $z$ e.g. as:

$$D_z(\phi) = \cos\left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right) - i \sigma_z \sin\left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right)
$$

Here, $\hat{S}_i = \sigma_i/2$ and $\sigma_i$ are the pauli matrices.

$\sigma_1 = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\
1& 0 \end{bmatrix}$    $\sigma_2 = \begin{bmatrix}0&-i\\ i&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\sigma_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\ 0&-1\end{bmatrix}$

Then we have given two states with a spin into the direction of the z-axis:

$\vert S_z= + \frac{1}{2} \rangle = 
\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 0\end{bmatrix} = \vert {\uparrow}\rangle $

and

$\vert S_z = - \frac{1}{2} \rangle = \begin{bmatrix}0\\ 1\end{bmatrix} = 
\vert {\downarrow}\rangle $

**Now my question is:**

With which rotation $D_\vec{n}(\phi)$ can the eigenstate $\vert S_x = +\frac{1}{2}\rangle$ be obtained using $\vert\uparrow\rangle $?

How can I calculate that?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to think about it is by thinking of spin as a classical vector.

What kind of rotation would take a vector completely along $\hat z$ to the $\hat x$ axis?  Clearly, this would be a rotation in the $xz$ plane, i.e. a rotation about $\hat y$.

The same argument will work for spin.  You might care to reflect on the relation between the classical angle and the angle of rotation in spin space, remembering that $\vert +\rangle$ and $\vert -\rangle$ are orthogonal vector in spin space but antiparallel in ordinary space.  That’s why $\phi$ is mutiplied by $1/2$ in your expressions.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Now I have the following result:

$D_y |\uparrow> = cos(\phi / 2) - i \begin{bmatrix}0 & -i\\ i & 0\end{bmatrix} sin(\phi /2) |\phi> = cos(\phi / 2) - \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\ -1 & 0\end{bmatrix} sin(\phi / 2) |\uparrow>$

And how do I now show, that this is $|S_x = +1/2>$?

Comment: @Armani42 You want to be sure that the $\cos(\phi/2)$ term is multiplied by the unit matrix matrix.  There remains for you to find the eigenstates of $S_x$ as combinations of eigenstates of $S_z$, and find the angle $\phi$ that will produce these eigenstates.  Can you guess $\phi$ from classical arguments?

Comment: Oh okay, and the Angle is than because spins rotate half as fast:

$\phi$= $\pi$ ?

Comment: @Armani42 why do you try it and see if the result is an eigenstate of $S_x$?

Comment: Okay now I tried and I get:

$D_y |\uparrow> = \begin{bmatrix} cos(\phi/2) & -sin(\phi/2) \\ sin(\phi/2) & cos(\phi/2)\end{bmatrix} |\uparrow>$

And 

$D_y(\pi) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$

But I can't take an eigenvalue of that :/

Comment: @Armani42 Obviously your choice of angle and simply transformed $\vert +\rangle$ to $\vert -\rangle$ in the $\hat z$ basis.  I think my comment about the “speed of rotation” confused you as you already have a $1/2$ factor in your expressions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67421/discussion-between-armani42-and-zerothehero).

Answer (score 0):

When you rotate spin operators i.e.
$$D_{\vec{n}}(\phi) \cdot (\hat{S} \cdot \vec{m}) \cdot D^{\dagger}_{\vec{n}}(\phi),$$
it is the same as if you would rotate (right-hand) the vector $\vec{m}$ around the vector $\vec{n}$ at angle $\phi$. It is a consequence of algebraic properties of spin operators (they span $su(2)$ Lie algebra). Following this analogy, $\hat{S}_{x,y,z}$ can be pictured as three orthogonal versors of the 3D Euclidean space. If you rotate versor $e_{x}$ at angle $\phi = -\pi/2$ around $e_y$ you will get $e_z$. So, in terms of spin operators:
$$\hat{S}_z = e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}\hat{S}_y} \cdot \hat{S}_x \cdot e^{-i\frac{\pi}{2}\hat{S}_y}.$$

Now your initial state is an eigenstate of $\hat{S}_z$ i.e.
$$\hat{S}_z |s_z=+1/2\rangle = \frac{1}{2} |s_z=+1/2\rangle.$$
If you use previous relation you can write
$$\hat{S}_x e^{-i\frac{\pi}{2}\hat{S}_y}|s_z=+1/2\rangle = \frac{1}{2} e^{-i\frac{\pi}{2}\hat{S}_y}|s_z=+1/2\rangle,$$
and according to definition of eigenstate
$$|s_x=+1/2\rangle := e^{-i\frac{\pi}{2}\hat{S}_y}|s_z=+1/2\rangle$$